# Java enum in Postgres using JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, java-11

I am working on the task where I need to handle a column which is of type Enum in PostgreSQL.
I need to map the same column into the Enum in Java.

I want to know, how can we do that like retrieval and set into the DB.

Env:

- Java-11
- PostgreSQL
- JDBC

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
When you want to retrieve it, this is the way:

```
tableObj.setEnumData(JavaEnumTest.valueOf(rs.getString("columnName")));
```

And the persistent is:

```
pstmt.setObject(1, tableObj.getEnumData(), java.sql.Types.OTHER);
```